# ping google.com by using IP address

Tags: ping, ip-address

```
host google.com

ping google.com

nslookup google.com
```

After these commands,
I don't know how to ping the server by using IP address.

Comment: http://bfy.tw/HSfR

Comment: I already did. But I couldn't find the one that truly related to my problems. And I don't get how to associate IP address with ping. I use ping usually when it's url ...

Comment: All the first search choices show how to ping by IP address. Was that the question you *really* want to ask?

Comment: @Rui really? [A LMGTFY link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109713/is-lmgtfy-frowned-upon) hidden behind another URL-shortening service?

Comment: Oh. The page already generates the URLs by default like that. While I usually do not entertaining the idea of investing more time in questions than the OP is (not) willing to invest in low quality questions, I honestly think this question is probably a  XY problem...given the answer appears so evidently in Google search, I want to believe it is not laziness and  I think the OP question must have some other root cause.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ nslookup www.google.com
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 74.125.68.105
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 74.125.68.99
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 74.125.68.103
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 74.125.68.147
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 74.125.68.104
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 74.125.68.106
```

```
$ ping 74.125.68.105
PING 74.125.68.105 (74.125.68.105) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 74.125.68.105: icmp_seq=1 ttl=45 time=35.7 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.68.105: icmp_seq=2 ttl=45 time=35.2 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.68.105: icmp_seq=3 ttl=45 time=35.4 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.68.105: icmp_seq=4 ttl=45 time=35.6 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.68.105: icmp_seq=5 ttl=45 time=35.9 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.68.105: icmp_seq=6 ttl=45 time=35.2 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.68.105: icmp_seq=7 ttl=45 time=36.5 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.68.105: icmp_seq=8 ttl=45 time=35.3 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.68.105: icmp_seq=9 ttl=45 time=35.4 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.68.105: icmp_seq=10 ttl=45 time=35.6 ms
^C
--- 74.125.68.105 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9013ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 35.216/35.620/36.554/0.419 ms
```

The following IP address ranges belong to Google:

```
64.233.160.0 - 64.233.191.255
66.102.0.0 - 66.102.15.255
66.249.64.0 - 66.249.95.255
72.14.192.0 - 72.14.255.255
74.125.0.0 - 74.125.255.255
209.85.128.0 - 209.85.255.255
216.239.32.0 - 216.239.63.255
```

Like many popular Web sites, Google utilizes multiple Internet servers to handle incoming requests to its Web site. Instead of entering http://www.google.com/ into the browser, a person can enter http:// followed by one of the above addresses, for example:

http://74.125.224.72/

[How to find Google's IP address?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27665581/4170720)

Comment: @meme, If this answer solves your problem, please accept the answer by clicking the answer button. Or, If you would have solved by yourself, please share the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you're wanting to do is use the output of one command (a DNS resolver like nslookup or dig) as an argument for another, ping. It should look like this:

```
ping -c 5 $(dig www.google.com +short)
```

You start with the command which is going to output the information you desire, and use command substitution, written as $(), to insert the output of another command. You didn't specify the number of pings, so I added `-c 5` but you could also use `-w` followed by a positive integer for a deadline in seconds.

For the command substitution I chose dig because I knew the +short option would cause it to output just a single IP address belonging to the first A record reported by the nameserver, which conforms to the syntax of ping. Other programs could be used as well, they just need to be capable of non-interactively producing the argument you need for the final command.